# How to change the log level of a kubernetes pod?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

when i give

```
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```

it give logs of the pod whose level is set to `info` 
how can i change this log level(both before Deployment and after deployment)?

Comment: That really depends on how the application handles log levels. That is not something that is handled by Kubernetes itself. Without information on the application this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ay,

As what I know you can't. Your containerized application write logs to stdout and/or stderr. These are then catched by Kubernetes.

It's the application responsibility to produce logs with info, error, etc... informations and format them to allow them being usable by an external logs tools like StackDriver (it's an example because I'm on GKE from Google).

So maybe when you launch your containerized application you can configure logs level to output other logs than info ?

Comment: This answer doesnt provide solution for changing the log level after deployment, as asked in the question.

Comment: Ay, it was 3 years ago. But I see that you put your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @KrustyHack have you got an example of how you formatted logs for StackDriver?

Comment: @zaitsman it's our dev team which did that in their codebase. They output logs in JSON format and output them on stdout and stderr. On infra side we don't have any log pipeline, logs are immediately sent to Google Cloud Logging by GKE and JSON payload is well parsed by Google Cloud Logging.

Comment: @KrustyHack yup that sounds exactly like what I need, do you have a reference or doco or a sample or something of what the JSON should look like? we already write to stderr/stdout but then we basically get two levels, and not any of the in-between ones

Comment: @zaitsman I think they use Winston logger with NodeJS. Here is a log output sample : https://gist.github.com/KrustyHack/01985acdc55429a95b9a08cfeea4d65e.

Note that we only set jsonPayload, other fields are managed by GCP.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you specify the `LOG_LEVEL`( **i am referring `LOG_LEVEL` as environment variable that will be later used by the application**) in the application manifest (xyz.yaml). So when a pod is deployed it uses the `LOG_LEVEL` specified in manifest and configures the application to generate logs of the specified level.

Once the pod is launched you cannot change the log level unless you delete it first and redeploy the pod using the updated manifest.

**WORKAROUND**

Instead of passing the `LOG_LEVEL` via environment variable you can you some external tool like zookeeper for the configuration management of your application. For this approach, you need to program your application in a way that whenever a change is detected on a zookeeper node it should restart itself. I hope it makes sense, if you need help for this approach then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have myself recently had the same issue.

Have a look on my answer here.
[Dynamically change log levels across all instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258121/dynamically-change-log-levels-across-all-instances/75889841#75889841)

Basically you can do that with an external log config file and setup an automatic scan of that file (assuming it has this feature, logback and log4j have it).