# Dynamically change log levels across all instances

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, logging, microservices, production-environment

Let's say, I have a spring boot application where I am using Log4j for logging.
In there, I want to change the log level dynamically without staring the whole application.
This can be achieved by exposing some endpoint to set the levels.
But, at production level, there might be **multiple instances of the same application** running across different servers.
So, how can we set the logging levels dynamically across all the container instances running the applications which are managed by kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how config maps on K8s will solve the probleme.
The environment variable, command line arguments and config files are used/read once the application is started. Any change on them wont be reflacted to the app, without a restart.

One solution that I use is to set a scan interval on the logger library (log4j or logback).
For example on logback there is a auto-scan configuration parameter
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan.

This allows the application to check regularly with the defined interval the changes on the config file where you define the log-levels.
Hence even if you use multiple instances of your application, all of them will scan the same config file and be updated without a restart.